# Packages listed in Imports of loaded package not listed in loaded pacakges in sessionInfo

Tags: r, reproducible-research

How do I get packages that are imported by another package and their versions?

I was under the impression that if I load package A and package A lists package B under `Imports:` in it's `DESCRIPTION`, then `sessionInfo()` should list package B under "loaded via a namespace (and not attached):".

This does not seem to be the case. Is there a simple way of getting a list of those packages?

My use case would be to document what packages in what versions are used in a simulation study. But this is definitely also helpful for some reproducible examples, etc.

It seems saving the output of `sessionInfo()` is not enough to thoroughly document what packages are used in a session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found out more about the behaviour of `sessionInfo` and a possible solution to my problem.

After calling the function that imports the imported package via `::` the imported package is listed in the output of `sessionInfo()`. So to get a really reproducible example or to completely document the used packages run `sessionInfo()` after your code not before.

A solution to get all potentially imported packages from the dependencies, is the following script using the `pkgdepends` package:

```
library(pkgdepends)

# load packages to be attached here

sessionInfo() |> 
  _$otherPkgs |> 
  names()

deps <- sessionInfo() |> 
  _$otherPkgs |> 
  names() |>
  new_pkg_deps()

deps$solve()

deps$get_solution()$data |> 
  subset(select=c("ref", "old_version"))
```

Edit: the behaviour that a package is only loaded on use and not attached is also described [here](https://r-pkgs.org/dependencies-mindset-background.html#sec-dependencies-imports-vs-depends) in the r-pkgs book.